# Как делать запросы yandex gpt api в js на сервере node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yandex-gpt

Не могу понять как делать запросы к yandex gpt api и получать ответ

```
async function query() {
  await fetch('https://llm.api.cloud.yandex.net/foundationModels/v1/completion', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Api-Key xxxxxx`,
    },
    json: {
      "modelUri": "gpt://xxxxxxxx/yandexgpt-lite",
      "completionOptions": {
        "stream": true,
        "temperature": 0.6,
        "maxTokens": "2000"
      },
      "messages": [
        {
          "role": "system",
          "text": "Ты профессиональный математик"
        },
        {
          "role": "user",
          "text": "Сколько будет 2+9"
        }
      ]
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log(response.json())
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    })
}
```

Этот код не работает.

С другой стороны пробовал тоже самое на python и все работает

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: нет `, json: {}`, есть `, body: JSON.stringify(...)` https://github.com/nodejs/undici/blob/3fd7bf3a34f593c7d4fb03e48559755c659d1f1a/types/fetch.d.ts#L108

Comment: ну и вообще, откуда мы знаем что означает ваше "не работает". ошибка (какая)? ещё других 100500 вариантов